# How to define a hypercube similarly to n-spheres?

Tags: geometry

The definition of an n-sphere is:

> A set of all points at a distance *R*, from a centre *c*, in an n-dimensional Euclidian Space.

Is it possible to similarly define a hypercube?

Comment: Probably the exact same definition, just use the maximum distance metric.

Comment: @InterstellarProbe thank you I never heard of it!

Comment: The maximum distance metric is $d(x,y) = \max\{|x_i-y_i|\}$ where $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n, 1\le i \le n$. This is also called the infinity norm distance.

Answer (score 0):

In the standard coordinate system the $2^n$ points all of whose coordinates are $0$ or $1$ are the vertices of a hypercube.

If you want a geometric definition, edit the question to tell us how you would define a square in the plane and an ordinary cube in three space so we can find the appropriate generalization.